# Journey browser Java Chromium Embedded framework throwing error?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, chromium-embedded

I am trying to use a library called Journey browser which uses the Java Chromium Embedded Framework. I first created a Java Maven Project with Netbeans and I edited the pom.xml to match the values on the library's guide, to add the maven dependencies. (No errors detected) I then built the project to download the maven dependency and put their default code (modified slightly) in the main class. My IDE found no errors in the code. However, when I run the project I get a "no chrome_elf in java.library.path". I think this has something to do with embedding JCEF, but I am not sure how to add this to the "java.library.path" in Netbeans.

How do I fix this "chrome_elf" problem?
Also, if I am able to fix this will it be an error for production if someone doesn't have "chrome_elf" installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Windows**

This happens because the `chrome_elf.dll` (on Windows) file cannot be found.

Java is looking for this file on `java.library.path` - which (on my machine, anyway) refers to all the locations referenced by the Windows `%path%` environment variable.

One way to fix this is to download one of the pre-built distributions from that GitHub page (for example the Windows one, referred to [here](https://github.com/CodeBrig/Journey#windows-64bit-powershell)):

```
https://github.com/CodeBrig/Journey/releases/download/0.4.0-78-assets/jcef-distrib-windows64.zip
```

Then unzip the resulting `jcef-distrib-windows64.zip`. In the `win64\bin\lib\win64` directory under that main directory you will find the `chrome_elf.dll` you need - and other binaries which are also needed.

Add this directory to your path - either by adding it to the Windows environment variable or via `java -Djava.library.path=...`.

For example, the path may be similar to this:

```
C:\your\path\to\jcef-distrib-windows64\win64\bin\lib\win64
```

This should allow you to run the demo code provided in the `JourneyBrowser` class. A browser window should open as a result.

Here is the browser:

[image]

The above steps worked for me - and the only files I needed to keep from the (large) distribution download were those in the `jcef-distrib-windows64\win64\bin\lib\win64` directory. It's possible that I already have some other dependencies which may be needed - so I cannot guarantee this process will also work for you.

**For Linux (and MacOS)**

I have not tried this on a Linux machine. But in that case, I believe you will need to download and unzip the `jcef-distrib-linux64` release - and then point to the `jcef-distrib-linux64\linux64\bin\lib\linux64` directory, containing `libcef.so` and other libraries.

Similarly for MacOS, there is a distribution which can be downloaded and unzipped.

**Alternative**

An alternative is to simply use the pre-built distributions provided on GitHub, using the commands provided. Obviously, in this case, you will not be creating your own customized implementation (so, no `JourneyBrowser` class).

Answer (score 0):

copy scr/native/Release to jcef_build/native/Release from the default output directory of VS.check whether the Release exists in java.lib.path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).